# SQL little table allocated in memory

Tags: c++, sql-server, sql-server-2008, memory, vector

Is there a way to make `SQL Server` to store a table with `10 attributes and 10 rows` like this on memory?

```
a1   a2   a3  a4  a5  a6  a7  a8  a9 a10
----------------------------------------
138 498  365 345 500 473 498 125 134 800
448 498  362 348 500 463 498 625 165 700
468 498  625 329 500 435 498 625 345 600
437 701  365 326 500 453 498 625 645 500
438 498  326 329 500 438 498 625 745 400
439 499  626 329 500 438 498 525 685 300
440 500  327 328 500 423 498 627 655 200
444 214  331 334 500 428 498 125 615 100
448 498  362 348 500 463 498 225 165 700
468 498  625 329 500 435 498 425 345 600
```

Is there a way to store this table in contiguous memory?

I was thinking to make somekind of vector and make the table a single row (instead of 10 attributes by 10 rows make a **vector with size 100**.
Is there a way to do this?

You may ask why I want to do this, It is because I would like to make some calculus *all in memory* avoiding writing or using disk, and then access the memory or **vector**  in C++ or .NET (maybe C#?)

Comment: Not sure why you got a DV for this, since it was a well-written question with a clear(ish) purpose.  I hate to think someone DV'd because you didn't understand something, which is kind of the point of asking on SO.

Comment: Thanks @JNK, I am searching and before I ask, I want to get as mush as possible information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't try to dictate to SQL Server how to handle memory for things like this.  It's a declarative language - you tell it what you want and it figures out how to do it.

Keeping it in memory only would be an issue for recovery.  That being said, once you create the table it will be kept in memory once it's written to disk.  SQL Server caches data pages, and something like this would be a single page so a lot of disk access shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: don't misunderstand me, I want to figure out some way to manipulate a table in memory, I see you say that keeping that in memory would be an issue for recovery so, I guess this could be possible?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way to force SQL to create an unrecoverable table.  Even temp tables in tempdb are written to disk - recovery is part of the architecture.  What I'm saying is you don't need to worry about it being in memory, since it will be written to disk once in a nanosecond and then accessed from cached page(s) in memory.

Comment: So, is there a way to know the memory address of the table? I want to do some operations with the table with .NET  **but all in memory**

Comment: Then you should make a Hashtable or .NET object.  SQL is definitely not the place for something like that.

Comment: Could you please give detail with that Hashtable or refer some tutorial of **memory management** in `.NET` of a `SQL Server table`?

Comment: It's not a SQL table.  You want something like a .NET datatable.  That probably should be a different question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx

Comment: Also Caveat: I'm not really a .NET dev, I just use it some from Powershell.  That's why I'm recommending a new question.

Comment: last question:  So is it possible to connect `.NET` with `SQL Server` and do that memory issue in `.NET`? I would like to do that memory thing to avoid wriring to disk, and avoid reading several times this table, (**it is a small table**)

Comment: It should be.  What I'm trying to emphasize is you **don't need SQL for what you want** from the sound of it.

Comment: Supose I want to do a Stored procedured that when being executed it does the memory thing, Is it possible with .NET alternative?...

Comment: Wouldn't a .NET stored proc be a function?  Can I ask why you are so determined to use SQL for this?

Comment: Well, what I want is: *To do all in SQL Server*, I want to manage memory. So I would love to have a stored procedure that stores this little table in memory, then let´s say C++,or C# read the table in memory... thats all, this is because I want to avoid writing to disk....

Comment: Two things you want are mutually exclusive.  You can either use SQL Sever ***OR*** or you can manage memory.  Take your pick!

Comment: So why is it impossible to do all in SQL?. Can I exec a stored proc and then the code outside (.NET, c++,c#) read and put the table in memory?... Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah you can run the SQL command and pull it into memory in your application as a Datatable object or something equivalent.  You can't manage the memory in SQL is the point I was trying to make.  SQL Server will store it on disk regardless.

Comment: Ok, I understandm could you please post some sample code or some example to get the whole idea?

Comment: I'm not a .NET dev.  I can show you PowerShell code which probably wouldn't help :)  I would open a question under the .NET tags for what you now know you want

Comment: one last last question, could you tell me why SQL can not manage memory, and only does: **the write to disk thing**, Does it has to do with the `tempDB` file?

Comment: SQL, as I said before, is a declarative language.  It manages memory and disk on its own. Part of that is a recovery model which means it will commit to disk as need be.  Otherwise if power were lost or a server had an issue you could lose data.  With SQL, you tell it what you want and it manages IO/Memory/CPU on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, Microsoft provides SQL Server 2012 with in-memory databases. It is very good news for project who requires a high performance database.