# whole table in memory SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, memory-address

I want to know the memory location of my table in SQL,

- Is it possible to know where is it stored the table or all the registries?

Comment: Have you simply re-asked your last question again? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6221621/27535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

Micro managing SQL Server to this extent would be a very bad idea. It is also not very useful information to have - what would you do with it?

Comment: And is it possible using any .NET language to know or map memory address of table?

Comment: @cMinor - No, this is not possible. Period.

Answer (score 1):

Not. At. All.

SQL Server is a database engine that manages this for you.

It's quite unbelievable arrogance if you think you can do it better than the SQL Server team

There are other more practical reasons (first thoughts)
- Internal structures change between service packs
- Transaction logging of any INSERT
- ...